# Enable/Disable AppInsights Availability Tests with Powershell Azure ARM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-powershell

Simple question, trying to use Powershell Azure ARM to Disable/Enable my Application Insights Availability Tests. We have scheduled reboots of our servers, and I want to black out those times so we don't record errors.

I tried the following

```
$alert = Get-AzureRmAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
        | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*isalive*'} `
        | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$vmName*"} 


Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule -Name $alert.Name `
    -Location $alert.Location `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -WindowSize $alert.Condition.WindowSize `
    -MetricName  $alert.Condition.DataSource.MetricName `
    -TargetResourceUri $alert.Id `
    -FailedLocationCount $alert.Condition.FailedLocationCount `
    -DisableRule `
    -Verbose
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermwebtestalertrule?view=azurermps-6.8.1

But I get Back

> WARNING: 3:34:18 PM -  The namespace for all the model classes will
>   change from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
>
> WARNING: 3:34:18 PM -  The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make it independent of
>   modifications in the model classes.
>
> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create/update an alert rule" on target "Create/update an alert rule: azecdag02 isalive-sitecore
>   production-2c06a496-3567-4871-a57c-2c516c0ccfef from resource group:
>   OAT_Website".
>
> VERBOSE: 3:34:18 PM - CreateRuleCondition: Creating location threshold rule condition (webtest rule)
>
> VERBOSE: 3:34:18 PM - CreateSdkCallParameters: Creating rule object
>
> Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: The setting already exists., Code:
>   SettingAlreadyExists, Status code:Conflict, Reason phrase: Conflict
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule `
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule], PSInvalidOperationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmWebtestAlertRuleCommand

And if I try `Resolve-AzureRmError -Last` I get

> HistoryId: 80
>
> Message        : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: The
>   setting already exists., Code: SettingAlreadyExists, Status
>   code:Conflict, Reason phrase: Conflict StackTrace     :    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet()
>                       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>   Exception      :
>   System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException
>   InvocationInfo : {Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule} Line           :
>   Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule `
>                     Position       : At line:1 char:1
>                    + Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule 
>                    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ HistoryId      : 80
>
> Message        : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'
>   StackTrace     :    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.AlertRulesOperations.d__5.MoveNext()
>   Exception      :
>   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException
>   InvocationInfo : {Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule} Line           :
>   Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule `
>                     Position       : At line:1 char:1
>                    + Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule 
>                    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ HistoryId      : 80

Comment: have you tried the $alert.IsEnabled=$false?

Comment: Sure it works, but how about committing it back to Azure?

Comment: I have submitted the issue at AI github, any feedback will let you know. BTW, I also tried using a Get-AzureRmResource and Set-AzureRmResource combo, still not work.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: The issue is submitted [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7215)

Comment: Any idea if this has been resolved with the latest release to Azure Monitor?

Comment: Actually, I have escalated it. But still has no feedback :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally was able to get this working, see the below script.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/16304431-possibility-to-enable-disable-availability-web-tes

```
#later versions of AzureRM don't support Find
#Get-AzureRmResources -ResourceGroupName "My_Website"
$allAlerts = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameEquals "OAT_Website" `
            | Where-Object -Property ResourceType -EQ "microsoft.insights/webtests" ;





$vmPrefix = "azesc"
$color = "blue"
$status = "True"
$alertIDs = $allAlerts | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$vmPrefix*" -or $_.Name -like "*$color*" } `
            | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceId


ForEach ($alertID in $alertIDs) { 

$alert = Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $alertID 
$alert.Properties.Enabled = $status 
$alert | Set-AzureRMResource -Force
}




$vmPrefix = "azec"
$color = "green"
$status = "False"
$alertIDs = $allAlerts | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$vmPrefix*" -or $_.Name -like "*$color*" } `
            | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceId


ForEach ($alertID in $alertIDs) { 

$alert = Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $alertID 
$alert.Properties.Enabled = $status 
$alert | Set-AzureRMResource -Force
}
```